# Did the Roman legions wear this type of boots?

Tags: roman-empire, uniform, fashion

I was looking at this [drawing of a Roman soldier](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/442197257148437168/)
(copied below)

[image]

About the boots: Is this pair of boots plausible for a Roman soldier (in any era/province of the Roman Empire)? I would like to confirm the historical veracity of the picture.

Comment: Long boots yes, but not that tongue in the middle. Socks would have been worn underneath to cover the front where the boot didn't wrap all the way around.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These boots are in the *[calceus](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/secondary/SMIGRA*/Calceus.html)* [style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calceus). As such they are quite [spot on](https://books.google.come/books?id=GxGPLju4KEkC&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=britain%20roman%20calceus) and accurate for a Roman soldier in [colder](http://www.romanobritain.org/8-military/mil_roman_soldier_footwear.htm) climates. But [not](http://www.personal.utulsa.edu/~marc-carlson/shoe/SHOES/ROME/romshoe1.htm) unlike the *caligae* we stereotypically associate with a legionaire's outfit these type of footwear were also found across the entire empire.

> [image]
>   via [an ugly site](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/613334042972091712/)

The actual styles came in quite a variety, though:

> [image]
>   "Replikat römischer Schuhe aus Vindolanda - gefertigt von Meister Knieriem"
>   by [Hiltibold](http://www.everystockphoto.com/photo.php?imageId=26224245)
>
> [image]
>   ["Right Foot from a Statue 2nd Century A.D."](https://benjaminproust.com/project/right-foot-from-a-statue/)

So regarding the era and provinces: this type of dress is not that typical for a common soldier of the republic, but early empire, since the dress/armour would have changed as well in later times. But this type of footwear was well in fashion throughout the empire:

> [image]
>   According to Simon James – who basically focuses on the [Julius Terentius wall-painting from Dura-Europos](http://isaw.nyu.edu/exhibitions/edge-of-empires/highlights/sacrifice) – the following elements determine the Roman officer: the cloak, the tunic, undergarment, breeches, footwear (the *calceus*), the purse, but most of all, the sword on a baldric, the military belt,  the golden finger-ring (the annulus aureus), and the military staff.
>   2nd and 3rd century AD depictions of soldiers. Attributes 
>   determining the Roman officer
>    <sub>[Marie-Louise Nosch: "Wearing the Cloak. Dressing the Soldier in Roman Times", Ancient Textiles Vol. 10, Oxbow Books: Oxford, Oakville](https://www.oxbowbooks.com/oxbow/wearing-the-cloak.html), [p 93.](https://books.google.com/books?id=FqRZBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA93)</sub>

And in the age of Trajan, found on his column:

> *Calcei:* A tightly-fit boot worn by officers and the emperor. Scenes 6, [25](http://www.trajans-column.org/wp-content/flagallery/scenes22-25/img_2061-vs-6992-s25-web.jpg), [104](http://www.trajans-column.org/wp-content/flagallery/scenes101-110/125_lxxvii_civ_8164-web.jpg), [118](http://www.trajans-column.org/wp-content/flagallery/scenes111-126/145_0096-web.jpg).
>
> *Caliga (-ae):* The open boot (in fact a kind of heavy sandal) worn by Roman soldiers, including the emperor himself. Scenes [16](http://www.trajans-column.org/wp-content/flagallery/scenes6-21/16_6958_web.jpg), [40](http://www.trajans-column.org/wp-content/flagallery/scenes39-45/42_xxx-xxxi_xl_7067-web.jpg), [66](http://www.trajans-column.org/wp-content/flagallery/scenes46-73/img_7153-adze-axe-web.jpg), [106](http://www.trajans-column.org/wp-content/flagallery/scenes101-110/129_lxxix_cvi_8172-web.jpg), [110](http://www.trajans-column.org/wp-content/flagallery/scenes101-110/110-rbu2011-lxxxi_cx_8184-web.jpg).

Comment: Presumably "in colder climes" the soldier probably wouldn't be wearing shorts, though?

Comment: @T.E.D. Ever seen a true Scotsmen in winter? The "pants" come down to when you would like to raise that issue. Early on trousers were quite disliked, barbaric etc. Then they went north and started to see how nice it is to have slightly warmer legs… But later they would even wear *long* trousers in Egypt and Mesopotamia. I feel that the Q should be tagged "fashion" as well.

Comment: @T.E.D.  in AD 69, the roman general Aulus Caecina, arriving  from the frontier on the rhine, shocked the toga-clad roman citizens of northern Italy by wearing  Germanic trousers [(Tac. Hist. 2,20)](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/perseus-cgi/citequery3.pl?dbname=LatinAugust2012&getid=1&query=Tac.%20Hist.%202.20)

Comment: lol. No way am I [biting on that one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman)

Comment: @T.E.D. ;) –– But seriously, my granddad used to spin the tale of going shorty to school in winter. Of course all the 14km through 5 meters of snow with fierce winds from the front… Funny though that all pictures of him in that attire seemed to be taken in other seasons.

Comment: I wear shorts (and sandals sans socks) in the winter all the time.  If it's not too cold for my face to be exposed, it's not too cold for my shins.

Comment: The second photograph is based on finds at the Roman Fort of Vindolanda part of the Hadrians Wall system. The state of preservation there has enabled archaeologists to find leather goods and writing tablets.http://www.vindolanda.com/_blog/press-releases/post/if-the-shoe-fits/

Comment: @LangLangC He is from Yorkshire I presume ?